# MYSQL database is showing blank entries when submitting the data from a PHP form?

Tags: forms, browser

I having a serious problem in my project but that problem is really new to me.

Let me explain you, when I'm submitting the data from my PHP form to database so it's working well and I have no issues here, but the problem is that It's working fine only with reputed browsers like chrome, mozilla, opera and other but when someone use
an android default browser to fill that form, the database is showing just a blank entry instead of data.

(means if I'm sending that form to 20 people than the chance are that 2/20 people's entry will show blank in my database even after i have applied the proper validation. So nobody can leave the fields blank. Those 2 persons are ones who aren't using a popular browser)

I think that it's a browser issue and I'm not getting what it is because I have tried severals android phone but it's not working only in 1-2 user's phone who aren't using a populat browser.

Is there any thing that I can do to run that code in every browser??

(I'm not adding code because I think it's working fine and I'm saying this because I'm facing this problem only in some browsers so I think that's a browser problem.? If I'm not wrong..)

Comment: Seems like a simple choice. Either rewrite those browsers, or rewrite your code.

Comment: If you were doing proper validation. That would include validating in the php program. That would not allow blank entry in the database. Never trust data from the client.